# how to handle a use-case where a node is sharing multiple BNO

Tags: java, corda

How do we handle a scenario when a node in CZ needs to access two different BN.
From my understanding ,I can see the following ways

1. We could have different membership cordapp with different BNO name configuration
   I mean this node will have cordapps 1. two membership cordapp with different BNO configured
2. with two membership cordapps with different BNO configured
   how will the notary will be configured in this scenario ?
   I am thinking that if we have common notary then different BNs will share the txn in this case

These are my assumptions:
reference : https://github.com/corda/corda-solutions/tree/master/bn-apps

Answer (score 1):

Great questions! The reference design of [Business Networks Membership Service](https://github.com/corda/corda-solutions/tree/master/bn-apps/memberships-management) assumes that you'd have a membership-service-per-business-network. Developers are supposed to fork the Membership Service repo, tweak the CorDapp to fulfil their particular membership requirements and then release it along with other CorDapps on their Business Network. So back to your question - if you'd like a node to participate in multiple Business Networks, then it'd have to have multiple membership CorDapps installed.

In regards to the Notary question. The best way to achieve interoperability across multiple Business Networks - would be to share a common notary. That would allow to seamlessly do cross Business Network transactions, given that their CorDapps supports those. Please also bear in mind that Corda design allows multiple Notaries to coexist inside the same global network. However in that case, you'd have to move states from both of the Business Networks to the same Notary first, before you'd be able to cross-transact them. Please see [NotaryChangeFlow](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.flows/-notary-change-flow/) for more details.

Hope that answers your questions.

Comment: thanks Ivanr3 ,Regarding notary , you are saying multiple BNO can share the notary but it will expose other BNOs txn data if notary is validating. My thoughts

Comment: That is correct. It's always a matter of trust. You always have an option of using a non-validating notary instead.